# Retrieving postgresql arrays using JDBC

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
  list     |  id  | 
-----------+--------
 {930,23}  |  1   |
 {2012,1}  |  2   |
 {5943}    |  3   |
 {6148}    |  4   |
 {1003}    |  5   |
```

Now, I'd like to use JDBC to retrieve the first column. I've learned that we can use java.sql.Array to do that. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html#retrieving_array), but when I declare the Array object like this:

```
import java.sql.Array;

while(rs.next())
    Array arr;
```

It issues a compile error:

```
[javac] /home/xxx.java:291: error: not a statement
[javac]             Array arr;
[javac]             ^
[javac] /home/xxx.java:291: error: ';' expected
[javac]             Array arr;
[javac]                  ^
[javac] /home/xxx.java:291: error: not a statement
[javac]             Array arr;
[javac]                   ^
```

It seems that Java is not recognizing the data type java.sql.Array. Anyone knows why? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use curly brackets with your while statements:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    Array arr;  // Add more code here.
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. But why should we use curly brackets when there is only one statement?

Comment: @Yang: Because the Java specification doesn't all you to create a local variable there unless you have a block. Even if it were allowed, it wouldn't make much sense. What would its scope be?